# Отдельный класс в названии класса

Tags: html, css

Смотря практическую верстку по html , я наткнулся на то что человек поменял название класса с div class="slider__item" на div slider__item active и добавил свойства к этому измененному клаcсу ,изменения СРАБОТАЛИ , при этом предыдущие свойства класса slider__item у него так и остались.

```css
/* Slider */
.intro__slider{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    
}
.slider__item{
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 24%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.slider__item span{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.slider__item.active{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro__slider">
                    <div class="slider__item active"><span>01</span> intro</div>
                    <div class="slider__item"><span>02</span> work</div>
                    <div class="slider__item"><span>03</span> about</div>
                    <div class="slider__item"><span>04</span> contacts</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Вопрос не ясен.....ну поменял шило на мыло...и?

Comment: Возможно вопрос и вправду не ясен , извиняюсь за это , просто меня удивило то что поменяв название класса у этого класса остались свойства от его предыдущего названия

Comment: никакого класса никто не менял. он остался. был добавлен ещё один

Comment: То есть получается можно создавать новые классы , просто меняя названия существующих классов?

Comment: `поменяв название класса у этого класса остались свойства от его предыдущего названия` он не изменял старое имя класса а добавил новое, второе(теперь их несколько). имен классов допустимо указывать несколько(разделяются пробелом).

Comment: количество классов может быть бесконечно (я утрирую)..... название атрибута `class` не говорит о том, что там один единственный класс с именем. Там их может быть указано много...... Просто так принято именовать атрибут ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос, так что ответ будет исходя из того что понял - классов может быть сколько угодно, все их стили будут применятся, но с оговоркой на то что нет одинаковых параметров. Например у двух классов есть параметр цвета теста - применится тот, что стоит последний из классов

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).